# Servicio en segundo plano en android Oreo

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio, android-service

He estado desarrollando una aplicación la cual ejecuta un servicio en segundo plano, el servicio funciona muy bien en versiones posteriores a **Android Oreo**.
Estuve leyendo y por lo que entendí era agrega un `startForegroundService()` y después iniciar el servicio con `startService` pero el servicio sigue sin funcionar, alguien tendrá un ejemplo o documentos donde explique el uso? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: MMM ,el servicio lo queres usar con la app cerrada? , el service que extiende de service, usa como thread principal el de la app, lo mas probable es que muera con ella

Comment: Si bro de ello el servicio funciona con la app cerrada, aunque se destruya o finalice, pero en android 8 eso no se ejecuta, al finalizar la app tambien el servicio finaliza

Comment: proba con este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed